# Get Identity Field out of KeyMembers

Tags: c#, entity-framework, identity, identity-column

I would like to get the `KeyMembers` where I have set in the Edmx the `StoreGeneratedPattern` to `Identity` is there a way to do this?

I can get the KeyMembers with this code:

```
private static IEnumerable<EdmMember> GetKeyMembers(string entityName)
{
    var objectContext = EntityModel.ObjectContext;

    var metaData = objectContext
        .MetadataWorkspace
        .GetEntityContainer(objectContext.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace)
        .BaseEntitySets
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ElementType.Name == entityName);

    return metaData.ElementType.KeyMembers;
}
```

The problem I have with this that it also returns foreign keys, but I just want to get PrimaryKeys with auto incrementing values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a given **MetadataWorkspace**, let's call **mw**, i use this:

```
var cSpaceEntities = mw.GetItems(DataSpace.CSpace).OfType<EntityType>();

foreach (var entity in cSpaceEntities) {
     var autoIds = entity.KeyMembers.Where(p => 
                        p.MetadataProperties
                            .Any(m =>    m.PropertyKind == PropertyKind.Extended 
                                  && Convert.ToString(m.Value) == "Identity")).ToArray();
            }
```

please test

Comment: For EF 6 users, Gert Arnold's answer is better because "IsStoreGeneratedIdentity" is now available

Answer (score 4):

The store-generated pattern is in the SSDL content of the EF model. Here's an example of how you can get the properties with identity specification:

```
var items = oc.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.SSpace).OfType<EntityType>();
foreach (var entityType in items)
{
    var props = string.Join(",", entityType.Properties
                .Where(x => x.IsStoreGeneratedIdentity));
    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", entityType.Name, props));
}
```

(where `oc` is an `ObjectContext`)

Comment: How would I access the IsStoreGeneratedIdentity Property, I am getting the message that its declared Internal - using EF 5.0 is it public in EF 6.x?

Comment: Ah, I guess that's true. Maybe George's solution would work for EF 5.

Comment: One more reason to switch to EF 6.x :)

Comment: Certainly, if you can though. It may take some refactoring, but the upgrade path is well documented.

Comment: @GertArnold Is "IsStoreGeneratedIdentity" property only available in version 6?
I created my code in version 4.3, I think, Maybe i didn't see it.

Comment: @George Apparently it is: *its declared Internal*.

Comment: This answer doesn't all cases since TPH inherited entities won't come in SSpace