# Entity Framework - Determine the HasDatabaseGeneratedOption setting for a given type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

For some of the properties in my DB I need to manually calculate their Id #, so for those properties I do `.Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);` inside `OnModelCreating`

Then, in the repository I have a method to calculate out the Id for a given type. I would prefer to have the system be intelligent and check to see if the `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` or `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` and either return the next Id or 0.

How can I check (from inside a repository) what the `DatabaseGeneratedOption` for a given type (T) is?

Comment: look at this, maybe it can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709302/get-identity-field-out-of-keymembers/21711234

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to George's comment I was able to come up with this solution:

```
bool? _sqlGeneratesID;
bool IRepository<TEntity>.IsStoreGeneratedIdentity()
{
    if (!_sqlGeneratesID.HasValue)
    {
        var items = (_context as IObjectContextAdapter)?.ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.SSpace).OfType<EntityType>();
        var entity = items.Single(x => x.Name == typeof(TEntity).Name);
        _sqlGeneratesID = entity.KeyProperties.FirstOrDefault()?.IsStoreGeneratedIdentity ?? false;
    }

    return _sqlGeneratesID.Value;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work if table names and class names don't match.

Comment: Not all my table names match.  I am getting back items with full names like `"CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.Trait"` and in all cases the name is equal to the class/type name. The only exception I am seeing is for tables that are auto-generated by the system for linking lists to entities... Maybe I'm just getting lucky.  But this works for me. :D

Comment: OK, you work code first. With database-first you'd get the table names if you query the store model.

Comment: Yes code first. Good to know though if I ever need to work with DB first (and I do sometimes). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment, your solution works by virtue of a code-first store model returning the CLR type names from `EntityType`. A database-first store model, however, returns the store names. These names do not necessarily match the CLR type names.

To make this method independent of EF's store model, we need to access the store-CLR mapping space (`CSSpace`) and find the `EntitySet` (by CLR name) and match its `KeyMembers` with the columns in the store model (`Property.Column`), because these columns contain the right value of `IsStoreGeneratedIdentity`. (CLR properties also have this property, but it's always false).

So this is what we get (as a method encapsulated in a `DbContext` subtype):

```
public bool IsStoreGeneratedIdentity<TEntity>()
{
    var entityContainerMappings = (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext
        .MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.CSSpace)
        .OfType<EntityContainerMapping>();

    var entityTypeMappings = entityContainerMappings
        .SelectMany(m => m.EntitySetMappings
            .Where(esm => esm.EntitySet.ElementType.Name == typeof(TEntity).Name))
        .SelectMany(esm => esm.EntityTypeMappings).ToArray();

    var keyMappings = (from km in entityTypeMappings.SelectMany(etm => etm.EntityType.KeyMembers)
        join pm in entityTypeMappings.SelectMany(etm => etm.Fragments)
            .SelectMany(mf => mf.PropertyMappings)
            .OfType<ScalarPropertyMapping>()
            on km.Name equals pm.Property.Name
        select pm
        );

    return keyMappings.Any(pm => pm.Column.IsStoreGeneratedIdentity);
}
```