# Access Entity Framework Storage Model at runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

So I have this other question here: [Entity Framework - Determine the HasDatabaseGeneratedOption setting for a given type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163841/entity-framework-determine-the-hasdatabasegeneratedoption-setting-for-t)

I think to answer that question I just need to get access to the Storage Model (the one that is created with `OnModelCreating`) for a given `DbContext`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from a given dbcontext...you can do this

```
var mw = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
```

see this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.metadataworkspace_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

to access the Storage Model you can do this:

```
var sSpaceEntities = (StoreItemCollection)mw.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.SSpace);
```

se this for DataSpace avaiables https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.dataspace(v=vs.110).aspx

and you can play around with this objects while debbuging, there is a lot of information you can find.